# Which exponents r>0 is the limit finite

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to find values of $r>0$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n^2}\frac{n^{r-1}}{n^r+k^r}$ is finite. I have tried to use integral methods for this limit such as $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n^2}\frac{n^{r-1}}{n^r+k^r}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n^{r-1}}{n^r+k^r}+\sum\limits_{k=n}^{n^2}\frac{n^{r-1}}{n^r+k^r} = \frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+(\frac kn)^r}+\sum\limits_{k=n}^{n^2}\frac{n^{r-1}}{n^r+k^r}$. So the first term, I could use the integral method to estimate. However, the second one is hard to evaluate. Could you please help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In short: diverges for $r\in [0,1]$, converges for $r>1$.*

- First case (simpler): $r\in(0,1)$:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n^2}\frac{n^{r-1}}{n^r+k^r} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n^2}\frac{n^{r}}{n^r+k^r}
\geq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n^2}\frac{n^{r}}{n^r+n^{2r}}
\geq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n^2}\frac{n^{r}}{n^{2r}+n^{2r}}
= \frac{n^2}{n}\frac{1}{2n^r} = \frac{n^{1-r}}{2}
$$
so for $r\in[0,1)$ the sequence will diverge by comparison.

- Second case: for $r=1$,
  $$\begin{align}
  \sum_{k=1}^{n^2}\frac{n^{r-1}}{n^r+k^r} &= 
  \sum_{k=1}^{n^2}\frac{1}{n + k} = 
  \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n + k} +  \sum_{k=n+1}^{n^2}\frac{1}{n + k}\\
  &= \underbrace{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1 + \frac{k}{n}}}_{\text{Converges (Riemann sum)}} +  \sum_{k=n+1}^{n^2}\frac{1}{n + k}
  \end{align}$$
  but
  $$
  \sum_{k=n+1}^{n^2}\frac{1}{n + k} = 
  \sum_{\ell=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=\ell n+1}^{(\ell+1)n}\frac{1}{n + k}
  \geq \sum_{\ell=1}^{n-1}  \sum_{k=\ell n+1}^{(\ell+1)n}\frac{1}{(\ell+2)n}
  = \sum_{\ell=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\ell+2} \sim_{n\to\infty} \ln n
  $$
  so 
  $$
  \sum_{k=1}^{n^2}\frac{1}{n+k} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \infty
  $$
- Last case: $r>1$. Same technique, and as before we only need to analyze the second term.
  $$\begin{align}
  \sum_{k=n+1}^{n^2}\frac{n^{r-1}}{n^r+k^r}
  &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=n+1}^{n^2}\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^r}
  = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{\ell=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=\ell n+1}^{(\ell+1)n} \frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^r}
  \leq
  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{\ell=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=\ell n+1}^{(\ell+1)n} \frac{1}{1+\ell^r}
  \\
  &=
  \sum_{\ell=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{1+\ell^r}
  \end{align}$$
  which therefore converges by comparison ($p$-series with exponent $r>1$).

$$
\exists L_r <\infty,\qquad \sum_{k=1}^{n^2}\frac{n^{r-1}}{n^r+k^r} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} L_r
$$

Comment: For the case $r=1$, it seems that one could easily show that the divergence is exactly at the rate $\ln n$. (By also getting an upper bound of $\sum_{\ell=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\ell+1}$ on the second term).

Comment: Your solution is very interesting. Thank you very much @ Clement C.

Comment: My pleasure! ${}{}{} $